# Retrieving data from Firebase into layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the screenshot of my Database and I have tried a lot to retrieve the data, but it always seems to return null. I am using firebase database. I wanted to know how do I retrieve this data into this layout. BTW, I am new to java and android so please consider it when answering the question. Another question I had was how do I pass the intent of the image when it is clicked. I am using multiple imageviews in my home layout and I don't understand how to handle that. Thanks in advance.

// products images retrieved from database
        mDatabaseRef.child("Products").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Product product = dataSnapshot.child("Product ID").getValue(Product.class);

            product_1_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 1").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_1_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 1").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_1_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 1").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_2_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 2").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_2_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 2").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_2_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 2").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_3_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 3").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_3_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 3").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_3_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 3").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_4_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 4").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_4_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 4").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_4_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 4").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_5_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 5").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_5_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 5").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_5_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 5").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_6_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 6").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_6_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 6").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_6_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 6").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();

            product_7_name = dataSnapshot.child("Product 7").child("Product Name").getValue().toString();
            product_7_price = dataSnapshot.child("Product 7").child("Product Price").getValue().toString();
            product_7_urlimage = dataSnapshot.child("Product 7").child("Product Image").getValue().toString();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

private View.OnClickListener HomeImageClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        Intent intent;

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_hotcakes_topleft:
                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_1_name);
                intent.putExtra("url", product_1_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_2_price);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_hotcakes_bottomleft:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_2_name);

                intent.putExtra("url", product_2_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_2_price);

                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_hotcakes_right:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_3_name);

                intent.putExtra("url", product_3_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_3_price);

                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_specials_left:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_4_name);

                intent.putExtra("url", product_4_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_4_price);

                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_specials_right:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_5_name);
                intent.putExtra("url", product_5_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_5_price);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_top_left:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_6_name);

                intent.putExtra("url", product_6_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_6_price);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_top_right:
                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", product_7_name);

                intent.putExtra("url", product_7_urlimage);
                intent.putExtra("price", product_7_price);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_center_left:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", "Muffins");
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("price", "280");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_center_right:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", "Muffins");
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("price", "280");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_bottom_left:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", "Muffins");
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("price", "280");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_categories_bottom_right:

                intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", "Muffins");
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("price", "280");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }


    }
};
```

[image]

https://ibb.co/hpviJk

https://ibb.co/et9wM5

Comment: This is how i have been retrieving the database data. And this is my database. What i have been doing is filling imageviews by retrieving data from the database using strings. I have seen many tutorials on pojo but when i use it it returns null.  https://ibb.co/hpviJk    https://ibb.co/et9wM5          https://ibb.co/et9wM5https://ibb.co/mpRnTk.

Comment: Share us some code.

Comment: what is this ????

Comment: show your firebase data structure image

Comment: This is how i have been retrieving data in my imageviews from my database. I have edited my question you can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

use orderByValue() this will do your job

```
    mReference.child("Products").orderByValue().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            ProductsClass productsClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProductsClass.class);

            if(productsClass!=null)
            {
                // do what ever you want
            }else
                Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: NULL");

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

// this is not part of your code but how to use hashmap

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //HashMap<KEY,VALUE>
        // just a example how to use hashmap in list
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
        {           
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("product_key"+i,"product_name"+i);
            map.put("product_key_image"+i,"product_image_link"+i);
            list.add(map);
        }
        // to get values

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> map = list.get(i);
            System.out.println("product name is "+map.get("product_key"+i));
            System.out.println("product name is "+map.get("product_key"+i));
        }

        //for single value

        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", "salman");
        map.put("full_name", "123123123");


        System.out.println(map.get("name"));
        System.out.println(map.get("full_name"));
```

**Output:**

```
product name is product_name0
product name is product_name0
product name is product_name1
product name is product_name1
product name is product_name2
product name is product_name2
salman
123123123
```

Comment: I had 2 questions with this answer. How do i fill in this https://ibb.co/eTBRM5 layout with the data from product image node, should i filter the data for only images from the product node. and another problem was that i was not able to understand how to fill data into the first screenshot layout using a pojo. I was not being able to understand how to pass the intent extra as you see in the question.

Comment: is there any way where i can load the images based on the product id and pass the id to the intent. Btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: just give me a plus point, use HashMap<> to store images link and use gird layout manager in recycler view

Comment: It would have been better if you could please show me through code how i could implement  hasmap as i have never used it before.